# $\varphi: V\times B \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by $\varphi(x,h)=f(x+h)$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $U\subseteq V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ open sets and $\delta >0$ such that is $x \in V$ and $|h|<\delta$, then $x+h\in U$. define $B=B(0,\delta)$ and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ differentiable. Show that  $\varphi: V\times B \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by $\varphi(x,h)=f(x+h)$ is differentiable.

if $h=(u,v)$ and $x=(x_{0},y_{0})$ I want to find $\varphi'(x)\cdot h$ and $r(h)$ such that $lim_{h\to 0}r(h)=0$ and
$$\varphi(x+h)=\varphi(x)+ \varphi'(x)\cdot h +r(h)$$
but by definition
$$\varphi(x+h)=\varphi(x_{0}+u,y_{0}+v)=f(x_{0}+y_{0}+u+v)$$
and by hypothesis $f$ is differentiable, then
$$f(x_{0}+y_{0}+u+v)=f(x_{0}+y_{0})+f'(x_{0}+y_{0})(u+v)+|u+v|r_{1}(u+v)$$
with $lim_{u+v\to 0}r_{1}(u+v)=0.$

I can choose $\varphi'(x)\cdot h=f'(x_{0}+y_{0})(u+v)$? and $r(h)=r_{1}(u+v)$?. thank you!

Comment: Composition of two differentiable functions -- namely,  + and f -- is differentiable.

Comment: how can I see that as composition of functions?  I'm confused

Comment: Put $E=\Bbb{R}^m$. Then, formally, addition on $E$ is a function $\alpha_E:E\times E \to E$ (just that rather than writing $\alpha_E(x,h)$, we write $x+h$). So, the function $\phi(x,h) = f(x+h)$ is really just $\phi = f\circ \alpha_E$ (of course for the composition to make sense you have to restrict domains appropriately etc). Addition is clearly a differentiable function (it's even a bilinear map, so it's actually infinitely differentiable, even analytic), and $f$ is differentiable by hypothesis, so $\phi = f\circ \alpha_E$ is also differentiable.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $E=\Bbb{R}^m$. Then, formally, addition on $E$ is a function $\alpha_E:E×E\to E$ (just that rather than writing $\alpha_E(x,h)$, we write $x+h$). So, the function $\varphi(x,h)=f(x+h)$ is really just $\varphi = f \circ \alpha_E$ (of course for the composition to make sense you have to restrict domains appropriately etc). Addition is clearly a differentiable function (it's even a bilinear map, so it's actually infinitely differentiable, even analytic), and $f$ is differentiable by hypothesis, so by the chain rule, the composition $\varphi=f\circ\alpha_E$ is also differentiable.

---

For the sake of argument, let's say all the norms below are the standard Euclidean norm. If you want to do it directly, there seem to be some issues with what you said. You wrote

> if $h=(u,v)$ and $x=(x_{0},y_{0})$ I want to find $\varphi'(x)\cdot h$ and $r(h)$ such that $\lim_{h\to 0}r(h)=0$ and
> $$\varphi(x+h)=\varphi(x)+ \varphi'(x)\cdot h +r(h)$$

That's not true, you want to find $r(h)$ such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r(h)}{\lVert h \rVert} = 0$.

With this, I'll assume you meant to write
\begin{align}
f(x_{0}+y_{0}+u+v)=f(x_{0}+y_{0})+f'(x_{0}+y_{0})(u+v)+ r_{1}(u+v)
\end{align}
with $\lim_{\xi \to 0}\frac{r_1(\xi)}{\lVert \xi\rVert} = 0$. So, with $r(h):= r(u,v) = r_1(u+v)$, we have to show that $\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)}\frac{r_1(u+v)}{\lVert (u,v) \rVert} = 0$.

So, let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $\lvert \xi \rVert \leq \delta$ then $\lVert r_1(\xi)\rVert \leq \epsilon \lVert \xi \rVert$. So, if $\lVert (u,v)\rVert \leq \frac{\delta}{2}$, then we have $\lVert u+v\rVert \leq \lVert u \rVert + \lVert v \rVert \leq 2\lVert (u,v)\rVert \leq \delta$. So,
\begin{align}
\lVert r_1(u+v)\rVert \leq \epsilon \lVert u+v\rVert \leq 2 \epsilon \lVert (u,v)\rVert.
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)}\frac{r_1(u+v)}{\lVert (u,v) \rVert} = 0$.

Anyway, if you analyze what I had to do, then you'll see that it's really repeating the proof of the chain rule in a simple special case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it solved my confusions!